# How can I use string format in c# property?

Tags: c#, string.format

This is part of my code:

```
if (domainNumberText == setting.NumberofDomains3AttributeValueId.ToString())
{
    numberOfDomain = 3;
    listOfDomain.Add(DomainHelper.ReturnAttrributeText(setting.Domain31AttributeId, attributeXml));
    listOfDomain.Add(DomainHelper.ReturnAttrributeText(setting.Domain32AttributeId, attributeXml));
    listOfDomain.Add(DomainHelper.ReturnAttrributeText(setting.Domain33AttributeId, attributeXml));
}
```

How can I reduce my code by something like

```
setting.$"Domain{numberofDomain}{i}AttributeId"
```

Is it possible?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, it's difficult to say any more.

Comment: You can. Use reflection.

Comment: john, thanks, I want manage my special attribute in nopcommerce. because is need many attribute, I named them by formatted numbers and I need insert many things in database, I don't want add to many code in order do simple approach. I think it should be possible.

Comment: if the class of `setting` is under your control, add an overload of `ToString()` to it that does what you need. At any rate, $ is a prefix for string literals and cannot be invoked like a function.

Comment: come on, he can't, he wants to use `setting.Domain33AttributeId` like `setting.$"Domain{numberofDomain}{i}AttributeId"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to do it, but probably a better solution will be saving the information in a Dictionary.

**Reflection:**

```
settings.GetType().GetProperty($"Domain{numberofDomain}{i}AttributeId").GetValue(settings) as string
```

Comment: Thanks, I think It will work finally, I post result for future use.

Comment: I think this is a correct answer. Your answer is based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I do this by some changes (Not exactly for first sample code:)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    var numberofDomainsXAttributeValueId = setting.GetType().GetProperty($"NumberofDomains{i}AttributeValueId")
                                                                                         ?.GetValue(setting);
    if (numberofDomainsXAttributeValueId != null 
        && idOfNumberOfDomoinOrMulti == (int) numberofDomainsXAttributeValueId)
    {
        numberOfDomain = i;
        break;
    }
}
```